# prefix or suffix docker container name in Jenkins pipeline shell

Tags: docker, shell, jenkins

I am doing the below docker command from Jenkins pipeline

```
sh '#!/bin/sh -e\n' + "docker run -i -v $workspace/tests:/root/tests -w /root/tests --name test ${awsAccountNo}.dkr.ecr.${env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${imageName}:latest testrun exec test.rb --input-file sample.yml"
```

where the container get a name of **test**

I want to make --name somewhat unique, so thought of doing it test-$RANDOM which will then give some random numbers. In an interactive shell session I am getting an output in the terminal. When trying to do that in the shell script it does not seems to work. May be some sort of usage error I think.

Can someone point me how to add suffix or prefix to a container name in docker run command inside a Jenkins shell.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you using RANDOM?

Comment: In a Jenkins pipeline shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$RANDOM is a bash-specific variable, it doesn't work with `/bin/sh` interpreter.
`sh()` function uses `/bin/sh` by default.

Also, you need to escape `$` sign for shell variables in double-quotes. To improve code readability you can multiline quotes: ```` ``` ````

So the script string should be

`sh "#!/bin/bash ... --name test-\$RANDOM ..."`

or

````
sh ```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -i -v $workspace/tests:/root/tests \
 -w /root/tests --name test-\$RANDOM \ 
 // ... rest parameters

```
````

Comment: Hi Andrei Kovrov, Your answer worked like a charm. Thanks a ton